# Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'onAdded'

Tags: extjs, model-view-controller, extjs4, extjs-mvc

I am using ExtJS4 with Java servlets. I am following the MVC architecture for ExtJS. I am trying a simple example of displaying a border layout but it doesnt work and I get the following error in ext-all.js in the javascript console:

Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'onAdded'

Here is my code:

app.js

```
Ext.Loader.setConfig({   
 enabled : true
});
Ext.application({
name : 'IN',
appFolder : 'app',
controllers : [ 'Items' ],
launch : function() {
    console.log('in LAUNCH-appjs');
    Ext.create('Ext.container.Viewport', {
        items : [ {
            xtype : 'borderlyt'
        } ]
    });
}
});
```

Items.js (controller)

```
Ext.define('IN.controller.Items', {    
extend : 'Ext.app.Controller',
views : [ 'item.Border' ],
init : function() {
    this.control({
        'viewport > panel' : {
            render : this.onPanelRendered
        }
    });
},
onPanelRendered : function() {
    console.log('The panel was rendered');
}
});
```

Border.js (view)

```
Ext.define('IN.view.item.Border',{extend : 'Ext.layout.container.Border',
alias : 'widget.borderlyt',
title : 'Border layout' ,
autoShow : true,
renderTo : Ext.getBody(),
defaults : {
            split : true,
            layout : 'border',
            autoScroll : true,
            height : 800,
            width : 500
        },
        items : [ {
            region : 'north',
            html : "Header here..",
            id : 'mainHeader'
        }, {
            region : 'west',
            width : 140,
            html : "Its West..",
        }, {
            region : 'south',
            html : "This is my temp footer content",
            height : 30,
            margins : '0 5 5 5',
            bodyPadding : 2,
            id : 'mainFooter'
        }, {
            id : 'mainContent',
            collapsible : false,
            region : 'center',
            margins : '5',
            border : true,
        } ]
 });
```

The folder structure for the Webcontent is as follows:

- WebContent

  - app

    - controller

      - Items.js
    - model
    - store
    - view

      - item

        - Border.js
  - ext_js

    - resources
    - src
    - ext_all.js
  - index.html
  - app.js

Can someone help me resolve this error?

Thanks in advance

Comment: show your code where you use onAdded

Comment: @IgorSemin  There is no 'onAdded' method at all anywhere in my code.. so I am not able to make out what the problem is.

Comment: I get the below error in the javascript console: Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'onAdded'  and the corresponding file for that error is ext-all.js

Comment: Did you create your app with `sencha generate app ...`? If not, and if you are on the inception of the project, consider doing so. Sencha Cmd does a lot of dirty work for you.

Comment: @Saki I did not use Sencha Cmd for creating the application. I have a question..Using Sencha Cmd can I create dynamic web project which uses java servlets for the server side?

Comment: `sencha generate app ...` generates sample, "empty" application that provides basic setup, directory structure, dynamic loading, etc. Then you take this app, modify, delete, add files until you make your own app.

Answer (score 0):

Ext.define must not contain configuration option `renderTo`. When components are loaded the body may still not exist.

Comment: removing the renderTo doesnt work..the error is still the same. I was able to get a simple form panel working However, border layout is not working..